# Javascript inheritance and JSDoc - let base class know about type defined in derived class

Tags: javascript, inheritance, jsdoc

Using JSDoc, is it possible to let a base class know about a param type defined in a derived class in javascript?

For example:

```js
class ServiceBase {
  constructor(repository) {
    this.repository = repository;
  }
}

class MyRepository {
  someFunction() {}
}

class MyService extends ServiceBase {
  /**
   * @param {MyRepository} repository
   */
  constructor(repository) {
    super(repository);
  }

  doWork() {
    // JSDoc doesnt know about this this.repository.someFunction,
    // because it doesnt know the type of this.repostory
    this.repository.someFunction();
  }
}
```

The main thing I'm looking for is intellisense in VSCode, but since the `repository` instance type is not known by the `MyService` class, I cannot get prompts for functions etc.

I think I already know the answer is *"no"*, but figure it's worth checking if anyone knows how to achieve this kind of thing.

Comment: I don't understand the use case. You can just move the doc to the base class.

Comment: Don't annotate the constructor argument (only) but rather the `.repository` property itself. Either on the `ServiceBase` itself or on the `MyService`. If the latter, you might want to consider making `ServiceBase` generic.

Comment: @KonradLinkowski By moving the doc to the base class, the base class is then tied to the derived class, when really the base class should know nothing about the derived class.

Comment: @Bergi assigning the injected property to the `MyService` class in it's constructor works, even having on the JSDoc `@param` annotation on the constructor only. This does what I need it to do; the base class and derived get a reference to the property, and the derived class knows which type the property has. Thanks for this!

Comment: How is it tied up when base class need this parameter as well? It's base class which force children to have this param not other way around. You are trying to make an impossible scenario where children is defining the parent.

Comment: @KonradLinkowski Sorry, I see what you mean now. In this small example, you're suggestion would work. But in a more realistic scenario, the `ServiceBase` class shouldnt be tied to a specific repository. There would likely be many services, each extending the `ServiceBase` class, each using different repositories, so the `ServiceBase` class should have a type that defines a specific repository (perhaps introducing a `RepositoryBase` class and having the ServiceBase annoted with `@param {RepositoryBase} repository`, but that wouldnt solve my problem here.

Comment: Why wouldn't it solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Use [`@template`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/jsdoc-supported-types.html#template) to create a generic `ServiceBase`, add [`@extends`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/jsdoc-supported-types.html#extends) to `MyService` and annotate `MyService`'s constructor parameter type with [`@param`](https://jsdoc.app/tags-param.html). It's going to be like:

```js
/**
 * @template T
 */
class ServiceBase {
  /**
   * @param {T} repository
   */
  constructor(repository) {
    this.repository = repository;
  }
}

class MyRepository {
  someFunction() {}
}

/**
 * @extends ServiceBase<MyRepository>
 */
class MyService extends ServiceBase {
  /**
   * @param {MyRepository} repository
   */
  constructor(repository) {
    super(repository);
  }

  doWork() {
    this.repository.someFunction();
  }
}
```

[image: Screenshot]